# Erlang shared ETS tables

Tags: erlang, shared, ets

Can the Erlang ETS tables be shared among different processes? Thus, if I have two processes running on different Erlang running systems, can I somehow link them so that all the changes I do in one ETS table will be reflected in the other?

Comment: have a look at http://yarivsblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/erlang-does-have-shared-memory.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within a single Erlang node, ETS tables can be fully shared by passing the `public` option to `ets:new`.  (Beware that the table will be destroyed if its owner dies, though, unless you have set up an heir.)

If you need to share tables across several Erlang nodes, you need to use Mnesia.

Comment: I would like to use the ETS tables to maintain a "shared" state between the different nodes. I was not considering Mnesia since this will be much slower in an update intensive task.

Comment: As far as I know, Mnesia is built on top of ETS and DETS. So it should not slow down your application more than a custom implementation, but bring you robustness and documentation. May be someone can give advices about the choice of transaction to use (sync/async, dirty or not)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "share" an ETS table between processes on different nodes, an ETS table is only accessible by processes on the node on which it was created. If you want to share ETS tables then you will need create a process on one node, the node with the table, and access the table from the other node through this process. It is not really that difficult.